# Experiments where the treatment is such that the act of applying the treatment to some people within the group and not others undermines the treatment

Tags: experiment-design, observational-study

Let’s say we have an experiment where we want to apply some treatment to some group to test whether the treatment “works”. But the treatment is such that the act of applying the treatment to some people within the group and not others actually undermines the treatment; in other words, in order for the treatment to work “properly” / to “full effectiveness”, the treatment must be applied to the entire group. In the world of experimental design, what is this phenomenon called? It seems to me like it might be considered some kind of “interaction” or dependency effect? Is there an area of experimental design that deals with this sort of stuff? Is this a case where so-called “observational studies” or “observational experimental design” are more suitable than the so-called “controlled trial” / “randomised controlled trial” sort of experimental design?

Comment: This sounds like an opposite of heard immunity or cluster effect.

Comment: I’d call it group effects. E.g.: exterminators are more effective when they can apply their treatment to every unit in a building.

Comment: @MattF. As per Demetri Pananos's answer, it seems to be "interference" from the "non-interference assumption". From *Design of Observational Studies*, second edition, by Paul R. Rosenbaum: 
"The notation for treatment effects appears innocuous, but it actually entails a fairly strong assumption, called “no interference between units” by David Cox [12, §2.4], namely “that the observation on one unit should be unaffected by particular assignment of treatments to other units.”" [...]

Comment: [...] In our case, assignment of control to one unit diminishes the effectiveness of the (actual) treatment to those units that are assigned it.

Comment: If you think “interference” is a good answer, then you should post it as an answer, rather than as a rejection of a comment.

Comment: "In our case, assignment of control to one unit diminishes the effectiveness of the (actual) treatment to those units that are assigned it." Sounds somewhat similar to vaccine trials. If everyone isn't vaccinated, it diminishes the effectiveness of the vaccine for those who are vaccinated. Is a clustered RCT not possible such that natural groups of units are assigned (together) to either treatment or control?

Comment: @num_39 Hmm, what do you mean by "natural groups of units"?

Comment: For RCT's the natural units are often geographic units, e.g. everyone in a particular village is assigned either to treatment or to control, or all the patients at a particular primary care clinic, or all the students in a particular classroom, etc. Do you have natural clustering like this?

Comment: @num_39 Ahh, I think you're speaking to an idea that I was thinking of: instead of just having a bunch of individuals and splitting them into groups, which is the canonical example of RCT design, we can use *groups* as the individuals and then split the groups into *larger groups* for the RCT design. [...]

Comment: [...] Assuming the entire problem is that there exists an interference effect where the efficacy of a treatment is affected by whether or not everyone in some group is assigned to that treatment, and assuming there is some limiting minimum group size where this interference effect ceases (that is, assuming the treatment doesn't require every human being / member of the population to be assigned to the treatment), then [...]

Comment: [...] you can design an RCT with this limiting minimum group size as what would conventionally be the "individuals" and then split them into (two) "groups of groups" (for treatment vs control/placebo). Does this sound sensible / is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes. For more on this, look at the literature on clustered RCT's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A term you might be interested in is "Stable unit treatment value assumption (SUTVA)".  The scenario you describe is a violation of SUTVA and hence makes causal inference much more difficult.

Roughly, SUTVA is the assumption that potential outcomes are independent of the treatment status of other participants.  That is to say, whatever happens to me under treatment/control is independent of what group you are assigned to.  From your description, this seems to be the case since the treatment "effectiveness" (and hence I would argue the potential outcomes of the participants) are effected by the size of the treatment group.

Comment: Ahh, yes. This seems to be related to the “non-interference assumption” and kind of the opposite of “spillover”?